# I have stored a regex in a variable that I initialized in a service .ts file, how can I use this variable on a formControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
 validationAR: any = "/^([0-9\s@,.=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF])+$/";
```

Above is the variable I used to store the regex.

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose , you stored your regex in a service variable

```
*//.. some imports ..
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService{
  validationRegEx = "/^([0-9\s@,.=%$#&_\u0600-\u06FF])+$/";
    constructor() {}
}*
```

Now, the component in which you want to use this regex just import the service in the component & you can access all the required service variables.

*

```
//.. some imports ..
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-data',
  templateUrl: './user-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-data.component.scss']
})
export class UserDataComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private dataService:DataService)
ngOnInit(): void {
this.userDetailsForm = this.fB.group({
      userMobile: ['',[Validators.pattern(this.dataService.validationRegEx )]]
})
}
}
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this common variable which you use it across the application, you create an appService in app.service.ts file and store this variable in it.

In the component where you want this variable, inject with appService using Dependency Injection there by having a single instance of appService.

In component.ts

```
    //.. some imports ..

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

    someFormControl: new FormControl(
        { value: null, disabled: false },
        {
            validators: [
            Validators.pattern(this.appService.myPattern)
         ]
        }
    )
```

This way you can use that variable in service file.